# Use custom formats in new Excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of custom formats that I would like to use in any new Excel files that I create.

I found this approach, [Save cell styles to use in all new workbooks](http://ttps://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Save-cell-styles-to-use-in-all-new-workbooks-0b3905c5-45d0-4ad4-be39-571f445d30cb), but it relies on using a template which I cant use as I am using a cloud server so I don't have access to the *XLSTART* folder.

Using code is fine if I must, but I don't have experience in this space.

I understand that I may be able to create an Excel addin to hold the formats, and create a new workbook from that. Is this [addin](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut03.htm) the way to go?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a desktop Excel program? If so, you might try adding another custom startup folder. (Depending on version it might be different, in 2013: `Excel Options` - `Advanced` - `General` - `At startup, open all files in:`.) Now if you put a file here, it will auto-open on Excel startup, just like the files in the XLSTART folder.

(But to be honest, I don't see how this will help you, since XLSTART - or any automatic startup folder - is useful if you want macros available. I'm not sure about templates.)